# Ubuntu22.04.1 can not power off normally

Tags: lubuntu

I upgraded ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.1 yesterday. After then, I can't power off my PC by `sudo init 0` and `sudo poweroff` completely,  the power light and the keyboard light also be on, and the CPU fans still run.

---

kernel :

```
$uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

images

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic                 5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic                 5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic                 5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic                 5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic                 5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic                 5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic                 5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-51-generic                 5.13.0-51.58~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic                 5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic                 5.15.0-41.44~20.04.1                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic                 5.15.0-43.46                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic                 5.15.0-46.49                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic                 5.15.0-47.51                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           5.15.0.47.47                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                 5.15.0.47.47                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

hardware info

```
$ sudo lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961/SM963
```

CPU info

```
架构：                   x86_64
  CPU 运行模式：         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  字节序：               Little Endian
CPU:                     4
  在线 CPU 列表：        0-3
厂商 ID：                GenuineIntel
  型号名称：             Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    CPU 系列：           6
    型号：               78
    每个核的线程数：     2
    每个座的核数：       2
    座：                 1
    步进：               3
    CPU 最大 MHz：       2800.0000
    CPU 最小 MHz：       400.0000
    BogoMIPS：           4800.00
    标记：               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pe
                         bs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_
                         deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_
                         adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear
                          flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  虚拟化：               VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                    512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                    3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA 节点：            1
  NUMA 节点0 CPU：       0-3
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Retbleed:              Mitigation; IBRS
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Comment: have you tried 

sudo shutdown now

Comment: I have tried `sudo shutdown` , same as `poweroff` and `init 0`

Comment: systemctl --help

systemctl --poweroff


I have never done this myself though.

Comment: systemctl --help | grep off


  poweroff                            Shut down and power-off the system
                         Currently supported by verbs: halt, poweroff, reboot,
     --no-wall           Don't send wall message before halt/power-off/reboot